# Selenium w/Python3 - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Newbie to automation with Selenium/Python. I'm getting blocked automating a sign up form. The drop down is a required element but I'm getting the following error...

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

I've posted my code below and can't find any answer online as to why this would be. Any/all help greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
teamElement = browser.find_element_by_id('id_team')
time.sleep(2)
sel = Select('teamElement')
sel.select_by_value("12")
```

The error is coming from the sel = Select('teamElement') line.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/jamesstott/PycharmProjects/basics/RunChromeTests.py", 
 line 40, in <module>
 sel = Select('teamElement')
 File "/Users/jamesstott/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 36, in __init__
 if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Comment: can you post your entire example?

Comment: which line you are getting the error?

Comment: Sorry, yes I should say that the error is coming from the sel = Select('teamElement') line.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesstott/PycharmProjects/basics/RunChromeTests.py", line 40, in <module>
    sel = Select('teamElement')
  File "/Users/jamesstott/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 36, in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select takes WebElement type argument not string type. change the following line

```
sel = Select('teamElement')
```

to

`sel = Select(teamElement)`

Full code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
teamElement = browser.find_element_by_id('id_team')
time.sleep(2)
sel = Select(teamElement)
sel.select_by_value("12")
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That worked.

I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

As per the API Docs, [**`Select()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) accepts `webelement` as an argument and is defined as follows :

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select(webelement)

A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an UnexpectedTagNameException is thrown.

Args :  
webelement - element SELECT element to wrap
```

But as per your code you have passed the argument **teamElement** (which was originally a *WebElement*) within single quotes i.e. as a `string`. Hence you see the error.

### Solution

Pass the argument **teamElement** as a WebElement as :

```
sel = Select(teamElement)
```